# ZPL import from printer

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

Is there any way to read back or import .zpl format from Zebra S4M printer to computer?

In ZPL II programming manual there is a Download Format command `^DF` which doesn't seem to do exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

^DF is for downloading the format to the printer.

^HF is for retrieving the format. You can also retrieve the format from the printer's web page.

This command can be found in the following manual
https://ups.zebra.com/UPSZebraWeb/support/downloads/ZP450/pdf/ZPL2-programmers-manual.pdf

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. However I have some trouble getting ANY response back from printer by using terminal emulator (PuTTY). Can you point me to some documentation where connecting to Zebra via terminal is explained ( I googled but maybe not enough). 

Also, what do you mean by retrieving the format from printer's web page? Some tool? I tried Zebra Setup Utilities where there is a send command message box. It works for `~WC` but I am not sure how to use it to retrieve the format.

Comment: If you are using putty start with sending a ~HS to the printer. This should get you a response from the printer to verify communications. Once you verify you are getting a response then send ^XA^HF<filename.zpl>^XZ

Comment: Got it working. It came out I was using direct serial cable instead of null modem one which is really required. Communications information is [here](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7923).

Also Hyper Terminal (the XP one) and putty seem to work a little differently. Putty seems to behave better.

Thanks!

Comment: When doing initial development with a printer using a network connection is nice as it does remove some of the problems that can occur with serial, parallel and USB connections. Glad to hear you got it to work.